# php require function using root

Tags: php, path, include, root, require

I have a site with several sub folders and an include folder in the root:

**for example** :

```
www.mysite.com 
www.mysite.com/includes 
www.mysite.com/includes/inc.php
```

then a sub folder:

```
www.mysite.com/sub1/
www.mysite.com/sub1/page.php
```

in page.php I would like to include the inc.php which is in the includes folder.
Is that possible, and if so, how can i do that? (tried `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` and didn't work.)

I appreciate the responses, it is quite urgent as I need to move the site to a new server in this format!!!! thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of why document root isn't working but when you do find out, use like this...
Have you tried echoing $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] to see what it outputs?

```
<?php

define(ROOT, '/home/www/web18/html');

require_once ROOT.'/includes/inc.php';

?>
```

Also, run... `<?php phpinfo();?>`

There should be root path somewhere...

[image]

Comment: tried this got something like what you posted (the same as what was echoed by document_root which didn't work. what else could be the problem?

Comment: @NinaNa, please post what you got.

Comment: /var/chroot/home/content/66/6207666/html

Comment: then this is what i getWarning: include(/var/chroot/home/content/66/6207666/html/includes/inc.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/66/6207666/html/sub1/page.php on line 19

Comment: @NinaNa, try `require_once '../includes/inc.php';` ... this is strange indeed.

Comment: That was the first thing i tried :( and got: Warning: require_once(../includes/inc.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/66/6207666/html/sub1/page.php on line 20 could it be a problem with the settings on the host'd server or s\t like that?

Comment: Yes, it most definitely is, PATH is correct in both cases, what are file permissions in your FTP, they should be `0755` (for php files etc)...

Comment: ok changed it, it had diff permissions. but still doesnt work any other suggestions? anyway why should they have those permissions? usually there r less permissions, no?

Comment: Change your hosting, godaddy is the crappiest I have used. Sorry :)

Comment: really???? oh well... nothing else i can do? btw, any suggestions for a good host, i was planning on moving actually

Answer (score 0):

You need to reffer the parent path in your `include`. Use `../` many times you want to reach your destiny:

`include "../includes/inc.php";`

How your `includes` dir is on the same level of your `sub1` dir, you just have to back one level to see it.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the following syntax in `page.php`:

`include "../includes/inc.php";`

It will include the `inc.php`.

Comment: nope. failed to open stream it looks like it doesnt recognize the .. syntax, can that be?